# Бэкап и восстановление БД в google

Tags: android

Есть приложение, которое работает с БД через Room. Как делают бэкап БД в google drive и восстановление?

Comment: https://zapier.com/apps/google-drive/tutorials/how-to-backup-google-drive

Comment: Имелось ввиду бэкап из приложения. Чтобы пользователь авторизовался в приложении и нажав кнопку сделал бэкап БД.